# Requiring ('image!xxx') cannot work

Tags: react-native

Upgrading to v0.14.2, require couldn't work.

The error such as:

`Requiring unknown module "image!xxx".`

Comment: Have you checked your Images.xassets folder to see if the image name still matches what is in the folder, and that the images are still there in the correct sizes? I know we had an issue with capitalization and this error being thrown when upgrading to 0.14.2 .

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Static Image Resource](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/53d20d54b4767f0408d33b0ee3de001a94b98dcb/docs/Images.md) after RN 0.14.